# A star search with priority queue

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, artificial-intelligence, anaconda3

I am new to Python and I am trying to do an A star search with a priority queue.
I found [this](https://github.com/melkir/A-Star-Python) really good code but I am struggling to transfer the grids section to solve an adjacency list instead. My heuristic function is conflicting with the next built-in function in Python. Any ideas on how can I fix that?

```
        #The adjacency_list of the given puzzle
        adjacency_list = {
            'A': [('B', 5), ('C', 3)],
            'B': [('G', 1), ('E', 3), ('C', 2)],
            'C': [('E', 7), ('D', 7)],
            'D': [('A', 2), ('F', 6)],
            'E': [('D', 2), ('F', 1)],
            'F': [],
            'G': [('E', 1)]
        }
    #I can also use a graph style as well
    #graph = {
    #    'A': {'B': 5, 'C': 3},
    #    'B': {'G': 1, 'E': 3, 'C': 2},
    #    'C': {'E': 7, 'D': 7},
    #    'D': {'A': 2, 'F': 6},
    #    'E': {'D': 2, 'F': 1},
    #    'F': {},
    #    'G': {'E': 1}
    #}
        import collections
        import heapq
        
        class SimpleGraph:
            def __init__(self):
                self.edges = {}
        
            def neighbors(self, id):
                return self.edges[id]
        
        class SquareGrid:
            def __init__(self, width, height):
                self.width = width
                self.height = height
                self.walls = []
        
            def in_bounds(self, id):
                (x, y) = id
                return 0 <= x < self.width and 0 <= y < self.height
        
            def passable(self, id):
                return id not in self.walls
        
            def neighbors(self, id):
                (x, y) = id
                results = [(x + 1, y), (x, y - 1), (x - 1, y), (x, y + 1)]
                if (x + y) % 2 == 0:
                    results.reverse()  # aesthetics
                results = filter(self.in_bounds, results)
                results = filter(self.passable, results)
                return results
        
        class GridWithWeights(SquareGrid):
            def __init__(self, width, height):
                super().__init__(width, height)
                self.weights = {}
        
            def cost(self, from_node, to_node):
                return self.weights.get(to_node, 1)
        
        class Queue:
            def __init__(self):
                self.elements = collections.deque()
        
            def empty(self):
                return len(self.elements) == 0
        
            def put(self, x):
                self.elements.append(x)
        
            def get(self):
                return self.elements.popleft()
        
        
        class PriorityQueue:
            def __init__(self):
                self.elements = []
        
            def empty(self):
                return len(self.elements) == 0
        
            def put(self, item, priority):
                heapq.heappush(self.elements, (priority, item))
        
            def get(self):
                return heapq.heappop(self.elements)[1]

        class Graph:

    def __init__(self, adjacency_list):
        self.adjacency_list = adjacency_list

    def get_neighbors(self, v):
        return self.adjacency_list[v]

    # heuristic function
    def heuristic(self, n):
        H = {
            'A':0,
            'B':1,
            'C':8,
            'D':9,
            'E':2,
            'F':3,
            'G':4,
        }

        return H[n]
    
    def a_star_search(graph, start, goal):
        frontier = PriorityQueue()
        frontier.put(start, 0)
        came_from = {start: None}
        cost_so_far = {start: 0}

        while not frontier.empty():
            current = frontier.get()
            

            if current == goal:
                break
     
            for (m, weight) in Graph.get_neighbors(graph, current):
                new_cost = cost_so_far[current] + Graph.heuristic(graph, next)
                if next not in cost_so_far or new_cost < cost_so_far[next]:
                    cost_so_far[next] = new_cost
                    priority = new_cost + Graph.heuristic(goal, current)
                    frontier.put(next, priority)
                    came_from[next] = current

        return came_from, cost_so_far

graph1 = Graph(adjacency_list)
graph1.a_star_search('A', 'F')
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Can you post a solution if so.